# Why is this C expression yielding the wrong answer?

Tags: c, math, sqrt

I have the following code:

```
double e = 36858.767828375385;
double c = 2;
double d = 67.877433500000009;

e = sqrt(e / (c * (c - 1))) / d;
```

The resulting value of `e` is 2, according to the debugger, but it should be 2.8284271.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the actual values for `some_value`?

Comment: On Eclipse printf result is e=2.000000

Comment: You need to show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We cannot see the problem as is.

Comment: This formula seems to achieve the result you are looking for `e=sqrt(e)/d ;`, the problem is not `sqrt` but the formula.

Comment: Yes but that's only one instance since the value of c could change for other cases

Comment: `c * (c - 1)` is the same as `c`, because `c` is 2.

Comment: Just type your formula in any calculator in your OS and see that the result you expect isn't correct

Comment: Just to say it:  The answer you're expecting happens to be `sqrt(2)` times the answer you're getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `e` takes the value 2 is because that's the actual answer:

> sqrt(e / (c * (c-1))) / d;
>
> = sqrt(e / (2 * (2 - 1))) / d
>
> = sqrt(e / 2) / d
>
> = sqrt(36858.767828375385 / 2) / d
>
> = sqrt(18429.383914188) / d
>
> = 135.754867 / d
>
> = 135.754867 / 67.877433500000009
>
> = 2

Perhaps you have the wrong formula?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh yes I thinkk it an error in the formula. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
c = 2;
c = c * (c - 1);
```

Evaluation will be  2 * (2 - 1) => 2        CORRECT (Actual result of 2);

It will *not* be 1 * (2 - 1)  => 1            WRONG (your expectation of 2.8284271);

This is what your confusion, I guess.

Comment: What is this a formula for?

Comment: I am not sure about the usage of this formula! I am just giving explanation to the original post.